# Completion handler confusion

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, sprite-kit

i'm currently using SwiftyStoreKit for my in app purchases and the function i'm using to try and get the information such as price and product description has a completion handler and I'm new to using completion handlers and read about the @escape if I want to return a string or let a value escape. My function code is as follows:

```
func getPrice(product: IAPProducts, completion: @escaping (String) -> Void) {
    var priceString = ""
    SwiftyStoreKit.retrieveProductsInfo(["Grant.Marco.1000Coins"]) { result in
        if let product = result.retrievedProducts.first {
            priceString = product.localizedPrice!
            print("Product: \(product.localizedDescription), price: \(priceString)")
        }
        else if let invalidProductId = result.invalidProductIDs.first {
            print("Invalid product identifier: \(invalidProductId)")
        }
        else {
            print("Error: \(String(describing: result.error))")
        }
    }
    completion(priceString)
}
```

The problem I have now is when I want to display that price in my label text it asks for completion information

**What do I put of for it?**

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call it like this

```
SwiftyStoreKitController.shared.getPrice(product:IAPProducts.thousand) { (price) in
   // set here 
   let label = SKLabelNode(text:price)
}
```

Also completion place need a change

```
func getPrice(product: IAPProducts, completion: @escaping (String) -> Void) {
    var priceString = ""
    SwiftyStoreKit.retrieveProductsInfo(["Grant.Marco.1000Coins"]) { result in
        if let product = result.retrievedProducts.first {
            priceString = product.localizedPrice!
            print("Product: \(product.localizedDescription), price: \(priceString)")
        }
        else if let invalidProductId = result.invalidProductIDs.first {
            print("Invalid product identifier: \(invalidProductId)")
        }
        else {
            print("Error: \(String(describing: result.error))")
        }

        completion(priceString)  // << here 
    }

}
```